# Is there a way to setup MDC permanent or default key/value pair

Tags: slf4j, logback, mdc

i would like to put inside the MDC a key/value pair that will be static among all MDC instances.

Is there a way to set this up?

I am working with java and spring if that helps

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand the question and translate this: You need to have a MDC parameter in your application, to put static content in your logback log-file. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. you understand it correctly. i know that i can just put the static content in the pattern but i want to use a tool that doesn't like that (which is a different discussion all together :) )

Comment: @Gleeb Did you figure this out? I want to set up a default logback config which will setup the MDC by pulling in some environment variables (e.g. which pod the app is running in). Something like `<MCD key='pod' value='${PODNAME}' />` if it existed.